# Stream my own protected tweets with Twitter API and Nodes

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, protected

I'm trying to learn some basics with Nodes and the Twitter API. I want to stream new tweets from my own Twitter account. I want the tweets to be protected.

I created an app in the twitter application manager and got all the access codes.

When I try out the following code I get new tweets when they arrive, but only when they public. As soon as I set the tweets to private I don't receive any new tweets.

Could you please point me in the right direction how I receive protected tweets from my own account?

Thanks a lot,
Marcel

```
 var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'myConsumerKey'
  , consumer_secret:      'mySecretKey'
  , access_token:         'myAccessToken'
  , access_token_secret:  'myAccessSecret'
})

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: 'myTwitterID' });

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet.text + ' (' + tweet.user.screen_name  + ')');
});
```